# IF Statement: Determine what was chosen. C#

Tags: c#, boolean

I need to determine which condition was TRUE in an if statement if using `||`.

Example:

```
if(trueone() || truetwo() || truethree()) {
   if([magical code] == trueOne()) {
      // ...do my code here...
   }
}
```

If `trueone()` was true, then say that `"trueOne was selected"`
Or, if `trueone()` and `truetwo()` were true, then say that `"trueOne and trueTwo were selected"`

**EDIT**: No switches please.
**EDIT 2**:

Heres a bit more detail:
The program is meant to look through a file and its lines using a `foreach` statement. If the line contains a certain keyword, then print it out to the user.
Currently, the program looks like this:

```
foreach(string x in lines) {
   if(x.Contains("stringtofind")) {
      Console.WriteLine("Found stringtofind at line x");
   if(x.Contains("stringtofind2")) {
      Console.WriteLine("Found stringtofind2 at line x");
}
```

Anything more efficient that can accomplish the same task would be useful.

Comment: why do you need to use `||` when you can just use `if` / `else if` / `else` constructs? or maybe even a `switch` case.

Comment: in my particular program, doing `if` and similar for every true/false statement would make it horribly long and very ugly.

Comment: is this a homework???

Comment: no. this is not homework

Comment: @StephanieMeanswell that's also why we have `switch` case.

Comment: I don't believe you can express "trueOne and trueTwo were selected" using just "or"... Are you sure there you've listed all requirements correctly?

Comment: i've never used switches, i'm not very fond of them.

Comment: yes, i've listed all reqs

Comment: In my case, @Aominè, switches would be just as long as `if`s

Comment: sometimes "ugly" is correct. Regardless, if the list of things to check is long... make it an actual list (for example a `List<Func<bool>>`) and loop on it.

Comment: So you have different conditions and zero or more of them can be true. Then you want to know, which ones are true? If that is the case maybe you can use bitmasks

Comment: @mayo this is exactly what i need..

Comment: You might want to update your question with that information, it's quite broad as it is.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Now, something simpler (if you just need to 'write' or put the selected options on a 'results' string), then you can a.- check one condition at a time, b.- every time that a condition is true, you can add that 'information' to your 'results' string.
Like `if c1() { resultString += "1 was selected "; } if c2() { resultString += "2 was selected";} .... ` at the end you will have "1 was selected 2 was selected 3 was selected".. (you will have to a add the "and" in some cases ) //bitmasks can be too much for that.. the idea would be the same but maybe more  'elegant'

Comment: Updated question to fit my particular issue :)

Comment: ok,, why not using another array/list for the strings that you are looking for?

Comment: @mayo that actually works! post that as a solution and you'll get your rep

Comment: done. Remember that having loops inside loops can make your app grows in a crazy way in terms of complexity, (look for `big-O notation`, etc..) Now, given the problem there is no way to avoid that, but is something that is good to keep on mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the original code:

```
foreach(string x in lines) {
   if(x.Contains("stringtofind")) {
      Console.WriteLine("Found stringtofind at line x");
   if(x.Contains("stringtofind2")) {
      Console.WriteLine("Found stringtofind2 at line x");
   ...
}
```

we can see that there are a pattern that is inside the foreach loop.
In order to remove the duplicated code we can put all the `stringsToFind` inside an array.

Like;

```
var lines = new string[]
{
    "line1  stringToFind1 stringToFind2",
    "line2 ",
    "line3 stringToFind3",
    "line4 stringToFind4 stringToFind5",
};

var stringsToFind = new string[]
{
    "stringToFind1",
    "stringToFind2",
    "stringToFind3",
    "stringToFind4",
    "stringToFind5",
};

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    foreach (string stringToFind in stringsToFind)
    {
        if (line.Contains(stringToFind))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Found {0} at line {1}", stringToFind, line));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to print the number of the line instead of the line, you can a.- use a counter, b.- use a `for` instead of the first `foreach`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    foreach (string stringToFind in stringsToFind)
    {
        if (lines[i].Contains(stringToFind))
        {
            // We use i+1 for line number to show that in a 'human' format.
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Found {0} at line {1}", stringToFind, (i+1)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I [was saying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244731/if-statement-determine-what-was-chosen-c-sharp#comment81439974_47244731):

> if the list of things to check is long... make it an actual list (for example a `List<Func<bool>>`)

```
var allConditions = new List<Func<bool>> { trueone, truetwo, truethree };
var trueConditions = allConditions.Where(p => p != null && p()).ToArray();
if (trueConditions.Length > 0)
{
    if (trueConditions.Contains(trueone))
    {
        // ...do my code here...
    }
}
```

> and loop on it:

```
var allConditions = new List<Func<bool>> { trueone, truetwo, truethree };
var trueConditions = allConditions.Where(p => p != null && p()).ToArray();
if (trueConditions.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (var condition in allConditions)
    {
        if (trueConditions.Contains(condition))
        {
            // ...do my code here...
        }
    }
}
```

Now, that was before you said you wanted to check...

> If the line contains a certain keyword

You can do that on the framework above:

```
var x = "some string here to search in";
var allConditions = new List<Func<bool>> { () => x.Contains("keywords"), () => x.Contains("to"), () => x.Contains("find") };
var trueConditions = allConditions.Where(p => p != null && p()).ToArray();
if (trueConditions.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (var condition in allConditions)
    {
        if (trueConditions.Contains(condition))
        {
            // ...do my code here...
        }
    }
}
```

Yet, since you only need to check for strings, you can make a list of those instead:

```
var x = "some string here to search in";
var allKeywords = new List<string> { "keywords", "to", "find" };
var foundKeywords = allKeywords.Where(s => x.Contains(s)).ToArray();
if (foundKeywords.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (var keyword in allKeywords)
    {
        if (foundKeywords.Contains(keyword))
        {
            // ...do my code here...
        }
    }
}
```